# Assigning values to classes in html - UI Bootstrap

Tags: html, angular-ui-bootstrap, thymeleaf, angular-ui

I have a dropdown in my html:

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
   <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
   Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Wherein, I'm using thymeleaf template in my html. I got to know that, spring thymeleaf does not allow any incomplete options in the working html.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

And while launching this via Spring Boot App, I get an exception,

> Attribute name "uib-dropdown" associated with an element type "div"
>   must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Can someone help me with what would I assign this uib-dropdown, uib-dropdown-toggle and uib-dropdown-menu options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append angular attributes or directives with `data-<ng att>`

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-uib-dropdown="" is-open="status.isopen">
   <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
   Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Venu. I will be using the values of uib-dropdown later in my javascript. Changing that to `data-uib-dropdown=""` won't be affecting the usage right?